# Numpy array : how to convert values of a 2D array into a 3D one-hot array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array 'ya' of shape (1000, 20) where each cell has values between 0 and 5. I would like to create a 3D array 'yb' of shape (1000, 6, 20) that I create with np.zeros((1000, 6, 20)), where the cells in dim(1) would take a value 1 in the column corresponding to the value of ya.

Example:
ya[125, 12] = 4 and ya[248,7] = 1

=> yb[125, 4, 12] = 1 and yb[248, 1, 7] = 1

and all other cells of yb[125, i!=4, 12] and of [248, i!=1, 7] = 0

Is there a nice way to do it without loops ?
I hope my question is clear enough... ;-)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Simplified example with a 1D array extended into 2 D and values between 0 and 2 :

ya = ([0, 2, 1, 1, 0])

yb = ([1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0])

The underlying idea is to replace values by 0 or 1 in a new dimension of the array.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. It might be easier to create an example of what you want to happen. I.e. a python output showing the desired before and after. I don't understand how we take `ya[125, 12] ` and get `4`.

Comment: I just added a simple example of what I try to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

Try broadcasting:

```
(a[:,None,:] == np.arange(6)[None,:,None]).astype(int)
```

Sample data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
m,n=3,4
a = np.random.randint(0,6, (m,n))
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]]])
```